# Amazon s3 file download from android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to make a demo app.

That download a image from my s3 server to my phones memory card.

I tried the demo codes and wrote the following. But the app force closes as soon as i run it on my phone.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
File f=null;    
    try{
    File dir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 f= new File(dir,"test.jpg");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
    }
    AWSCredentials creden=new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,secretKey);
    AmazonS3Client s3Client=new AmazonS3Client(creden);

    ObjectMetadata obj= s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("adj-temp","funflick_1.jpg"),f);


}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat output relating to the force close, so we can see the exact exception details?

Comment: Without the error it's hard to tell. Could be multiple things.. lack of permissions to external storage and networking on main thread are the best guesses I can come up with from glancing at the code

Comment: also check the permission for read write sdcard!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will work Happy coding

```
{
        String str_FilePathInDevice = "/sdcard/" + "/"
                + "RestoreFolderName" + "/" + "filname.extention";

        File file = new File(str_FilePathInDevice);

        String str_Path = file.getPath().replace(file.getName(), "");
        File filedir = new File(str_Path);

        try {
            filedir.mkdirs();
        } catch (Exception ex1) {
        }
        S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
                "BucketName", "keyName"));

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                object.getObjectContent()));
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));

        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            writer.write(line + "\n");
        }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
}
```